# How to detect camera orientation in android?

Tags: android

When I test my application on my Android One phone or Emulator itself everything is ok but with some other devices there is a problem.

Problem is, I basically send a camera intent, get the data from intent after user takes a photo and I set the pixels of an `ImageView` with whatever I get from the camera. With some devices (Samsung mostly) image is rotated, it's not shown as it's taken.

My app only works in portrait mode but user can also take photo in Landscape mode if he/she rotates the phone when taking the image.

Is there a way to detect the default angle that the device rotates the images and so I rotate the bitmap after taking the image?

Here is the code :

Sending intent :

```
File path = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), "map_roomie");

if (!path.exists()) path.mkdirs();

mFileName = createImageFileName();

File image   = new File(path, mFileName);
Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), AddRoomFragment.CAPTURE_IMAGE_FILE_PROVIDER, image);

Intent imageCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                         imageCaptureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                                            startActivityForResult(imageCaptureIntent, AddRoomFragment.CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

capturing intent on fragment

```
File path = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), "map_roomie");

if (!path.exists()) path.mkdirs();

File imageFile = new File(path, mFileName);

setBitmapOfImageView(mCurrentPhotoId, decodeAndReturnBitmap(imageFile.getAbsolutePath()));
```

helper functions :

```
public void setBitmapOfImageView(int photoId, Bitmap bitmap)
{
    mPhotos[photoId].setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    mPhotosState[photoId] = 1;
}

public Bitmap decodeAndReturnBitmap(String filePath)
{
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds    = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 512;

    int widthTemp = o.outWidth, heightTemp = o.outHeight;
    int scale     = 1;

    while (true) {
        if (widthTemp < REQUIRED_SIZE && heightTemp < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            break;
        }

        widthTemp  /= 2;
        heightTemp /= 2;
        scale      *= 2;
    }

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize          = scale;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the camera image show in the same orientation as the display, you can use the following code.

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
             int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
         android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
                 new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
         android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
         int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                 .getRotation();
         int degrees = 0;
         switch (rotation) {
             case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
             case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
             case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
             case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
         }

         int result;
         if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
             result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
             result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
         } else {  // back-facing
             result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
         }
         camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
     }
```

For further info, refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
What should I create and pass as arguments to second and third parameters?

Answer (score 1):

This solution works properly for me.

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation (Activity activity, int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera){
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look -

```
    private int getCameraId() {
        int curCameraId = 0;

        if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 0) {
            curCameraId = (curCameraId + 1) % Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        } else {
            curCameraId = 0;
        }
        return curCameraId;
    }

    public void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int curCameraId) {
        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open(curCameraId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();

        Camera.getCameraInfo(curCameraId, info);
        WindowManager winManager = (WindowManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        int rotation = winManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        int result;

        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
        } else {  // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    }
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.setDisplayOrientation(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue using an ExifInterface. But still it would be great if someone can shed some light on detecting default angle applied on images when taking a picture.

Here is the code :

```
public Bitmap decodeAndReturnBitmap(String filePath)
{
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds    = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 512;

    int widthTemp = o.outWidth, heightTemp = o.outHeight;
    int scale     = 1;

    while (true) {
        if (widthTemp < REQUIRED_SIZE && heightTemp < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            break;
        }

        widthTemp  /= 2;
        heightTemp /= 2;
        scale      *= 2;
    }

    ExifInterface exifInterface = null;

    try {
        exifInterface = new ExifInterface(filePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    switch(orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 :
            matrix.setRotate(90.0f);
            break;

        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            matrix.setRotate(180.0f);
            break;

       case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            matrix.setRotate(270.0f);
            break;

    }

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize          = scale;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```